# Difference between @Binding and Binding<Type> in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

I understand that `@Binding` is a property wrapper and I believe that `Binding<Type>` is a form of type casting but what is the difference in practical terms?

For example declaring a var like:

```swift
@Binding
var hidden: Bool
```

versus

```swift
var hidden: Binding<Bool>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're correct that `@Binding` is a property wrapper. More specifically, it's a [`DynamicProperty`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty), which means that it has the ability to notify its parent `View` to trigger a render when its value changes.

`@Binding` does this while maintaining a fairly transparent interface to the underlying `Bool`. For example, in a `View` where you had `@Binding var hidden: Bool` defined as a property, you could write `hidden = false` or `Text(hidden ? "hidden" : "visible")`, just as if `hidden` were a regular `Bool`. If you want to get access to the underlying `Binding<Bool>`, you can use `$`:

```
$hidden //<-- Binding<Bool>
```

In your second example, `Binding<Bool>` is not "type casting", but rather "type annotation" -- by writing `var hidden: Binding<Bool>`, you're telling the compiler that `hidden` is `Binding<Bool>`. Because it's `Binding<Bool>` and not just a `Bool` (and not a `@Binding`), you can't treat it like you would if it were just a `Bool`. For example, `hidden = false` will *not* work with `Binding<Bool>`. Instead, to access the underlying `Bool` value, you can use its `.wrappedValue` property: `hidden.wrappedValue = false`.

The two are are very similar, but different in a couple of important ways (like those detailed above). **In practical terms:**

- If you're using a binding as a property on a `View`, you'll likely end up using `@Binding`.
- If you're the binding it outside of a view (and thus don't have use of the DynamicProperty aspect), you'll likely use `Binding<Bool>` (*technically*, nothing is stopping you from using `@Binding` outside of a `View`, but it's a semantically odd decision).

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation!